# Why does Exodia still appear in the intro of the first Yu-Gi-Oh! series?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Every time I watch *Yu-Gi-Oh!*, I see Exodia and I remember that Weevil throws all of the pieces but Joe saves a few, not all of them, so Yugi can’t summon him. However, The Exodia is still shown in the intro.

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intro sequence showing of monsters at the end only changes 3 times in the original *Yu-Gi-Oh!* series

[image]

At the start of the series, Yugi became famous for not only defeating Kaiba but also summoning Exodia which is shown in the flashback prior to his grandfather saying it hadn't been done before. So, Exodia became an iconic card to Yugi's fame, enough so for Weevil to go for Exodia only.

It's not until the "Virtual World" arc (season 3) that Slifer the Sky Dragon takes Exodia's place even though Slifer is never summoned by Yugi until the next arc/season. However, Slifer became an iconic card of Yugi just like how Obelisk was Kaiba's and Ra was Marik's until Yugi won all 3 God Cards, which is reflected by the change of the intro's end of the next arc/season despite that Yugi never summons all 3

> until the very end of the final season by Atem when he dueled Yugi

So ultimately, the monsters shown at the end aren't necessarily monsters that Yugi has summoned but more iconic to Yugi as a character.